# Multi threaded function pointers C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, pointer-to-member

I am writing a pattern generator class in c++ which has a detached thread to run in the background.

I have a functioning code now that executes a single function. But I want to make it a function pointer so that I can call other functions.

The code now looks like this:

```cpp
// This is the function I want to "replace" with other similar functions
int Patterns::patternGen(int begin, int end)
{
    time_proxy now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::random_device seed;
    std::mt19937 engine(seed());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> uniformDist(begin, end);
    time_proxy done = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    m_evalTime = done - now;

    return uniformDist(engine);
}

// This is the threaded func
void Patterns::threadedTick(std::chrono::duration<float> evaltime, unsigned long milliseconds, int& newInput, int beg, int end)
{
    std::atomic_ref<int> newOutput(newInput);
    std::thread([this, newOutput, beg, end, evaltime, milliseconds]() {
        while (true) {
            newOutput = patternGen(beg, end); // This is the call to the function I want to replace with a function pointer.
            auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds) - evaltime;
            std::cout << "Thread waiting\n";
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
        }
    }).detach();
}
```

Is there a way to replace the function call in the second function with a function pointer?

I still dont understand function pointers enough to figure out how to pass it into a another function that passes it to a thread.

Comment: "_**has a** detached thread_" makes it sound like it shouldn't be detached at all. In C++20 you could use [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) instead.

Comment: well I could declare the thread as a member in the class and detach it in the destructor.. Did not know about jthread. thank you. I will look into it

Comment: Why on earth would you want to detach at all? If it _has a_ worker thread, make it join it when it destructs. `jthread` does that automatically.

Comment: oh because its in a while true loop. if I join it, wont that bork?
The idea is that it calls the function at an interval, pretty much constantly. I may replace `true` with a bool variable to turn it off if necessary but i pretty much want it to keep running perpetually

Comment: If an object creates a thread to do some background work, joining that thread when the object is destroyed is usually the correct thing to do. If you have a thread pool, it's a different matter.

Comment: alright. that makes a lot of sense. Thanks. i will do jthread &/or join it when it goes out of scope.